# Android - Tabs as part of Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

I'm trying to write an activity that has a RelativeLayout on top with options, and then a tabhost below that layout that contains 2 tabs.

Unfortunately, when I add a tabhost to my layout, it gets put on top of the activity it's in, no matter where it's defined in the layout.  According to the docs **" The TabHost must be the root node for the layout"**, does this mean I can't have it being part of the layout as opposed to the topmost element?

I tried different heights for the TabHost, from fill_parent to wrap_content to 50dip, but nothing affected placement and it just was drawn on top of all the other elements.

Thanks

Comment: It's doable - I have a `TabActivity` which has a `LinearLayout` containg an `ImageView` and a `TextView` at the top of the screen and the tabs below that, for example. Post the layout file you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t confuse a `TabHost` view with a `TabActivity`. You can have an `Activity` which is not a `TabActivity`, and within its layout, any number of `TabHost` views, arranged and grouped however you like.

For example, see  [this sample code](https://github.com/ldo/android-custom-tabs), which displays two different sets of tabs at once so you can compare the appearance of custom versus default styles.